# Creating an Object implementing a Typescript Interface

Tags: typescript

I'm providing a public Interface to my data, but for performance and memory reasons I want to use an Object and definitely not a Class. There's no code on the Interface, it is purely a data structure.

I want to be able to declare my Object as using the Interface so that if I change the Interface it'll show up as an error and doesn't get missed.

```
interface DataStructure {
   key1: string;
   key2: number;
   key3: boolean;
   key4: null;
}

const defaultData: {[key: string]: PropertyDescriptor} = {
   key1: {writable: true, enumerable: true},
   key2: {writable: true, enumerable: true},
   key3: {writable: true, enumerable: true}
};

var myData = Object.create(null, defaultData);
```

I want this to report an error for missing `key4` in the `defaultData` Object, but can't quite figure out how right now.

*(This is needed due to potentially tens of thousands of objects needing the same structure, and not wanting to waste GC on them when it's easier to just re-use them - also wanting simply Map stores, so no need for the Object prototype chain.)*

Comment: Can you not implement a minimal version of the interface? Kinda like `class SimpleDataStructure implements DataStructure`?

Comment: Have you tried `var myData: DataStructure = Object.create(null, defaultData);`?

Comment: @Icepickle. This is a bit beyond my level of expertise with Typescript ATM.. But I believe the inclusion of PropertyDescriptor implies OP is doing something like creating an annotation / Decorator, that can be used for things like Reflection.

Comment: @Icepickle Unfortunately a class would still be sitting on top of Object, and I need it to sit on `null` instead.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That wouldn't throw an error, as `Object.create` returns `any` - so there's nothing for it to complain about ;-)

Comment: @JGFMK I'm actually in the middle of rewriting VelocityJS, and making use of caching to prevent the Garbage Collector from firing any more than it has to - having recently hit some GC cycles taking several frames to complete (80+ms for 26mb), I'm trying to reduce overhead as much as possible to try and stop it from ever coming across a GC cycle that makes an animation stutter. Making use of doubly-linked lists as it makes a lot of sense and nobody else seems to be doing it that way outside the browsers with `Node` itself ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you're looking for:

```
const defaultData: {[K in keyof DataStructure]: PropertyDescriptor} = {
    ...
}
```

The compiler will then compile saying:

> Type '{ key1: { writable: true; enumerable: true; }; key2: { writable:
>   true; enumerable: true; }; key3:...' is not assignable to type '{
>   key1: PropertyDescriptor; key2: PropertyDescriptor; key3:
>   PropertyDescriptor; key4: PropertyDes...'.
>
> Property 'key4' is missing in type '{ key1: { writable: true;
>   enumerable: true; }; key2: { writable: true; enumerable: true; };
>   key3:...'.

Comment: Doh - I'd missed out the `K in` before it - hence why I couldn't get it to work - thanks!